# PayPal API transaction final status

Tags: api, paypal, status

I am using `PayPalAPIInterfaceClient` (soap service) to get information about transaction (method `GetTransactionDetails()`) and need to be absolutely sure about transaction status (it means - money has been sent no matter in which direction).

When the transaction is really completed and when is still "on the road"? 
For example: I assume, Processed will be followed by `InProgress` and finally changed to Completed or something like this. On the other hand, Denied or - I don't know - Voided will not change in future.

Can you help me please to decide, which status can be accepted as ultimate (like Completed, but may be even Completed must not mean final money transfer) and which ones are still in one of its sub-state?

I would expect simple "Money finally transferred" & "Money finally not transferred" result, but reality is different.

Shortly, to mirror transaction result into database and manage automatic transactions (from and to client) I need to know this.

I am using the `PaymentStatusCodeType` enumeration values and my service iterates transaction history to check if the money was transferred or not.

Answer (score 0):

Completed means it's done.  You may also want to look into [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  It sends real-time updates when transactions hit your PayPal account so you can automate post-transaction tasks accordingly.  This includes handling e-checks or other pending payments which won't complete for a few days, refunds, disputes, etc.

Comment: So, Completed will be the only status signaling positive result. Each another Not. I needed to know it clearly. Sure, I will integrate IPN notification to my server, but it is problem to broadcast to localhost while in developing-testing mode by now. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I would just look for completed before considering it final.  For testing, you could setup a subdomain like sandbox.yourdomain.com and make it publicly available.  That way you could fully test things like this from beginning to end using the PayPal sandbox.

Comment: Hello again, one more question pls. Does "Completed-Funds-Held" status mean final money transfer? If does, You previous answer is not correct, becouse it would mean, that "Completed" is not the only one. Would you be so kind and update the boolean values in my table please?

Comment: (Id, Name, IsFinal, MoneySent); 1 canceled_reversal True False;
2 completed True True;
3 denied True False;
4 expired True False;
5 failed True False;
6 in_progress False False;
7 partially_refunded True False;
8 pending False  False;
9 refunded True False;
10 reversed True False;
11 processed False False;
12 voided True False;
13 completed_funds_held  True True;.

Comment: Ah, yes, completed_funds_held would still mean completed.